# Node.js Express Cannot GET with https and parameter or errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, runtime-error

I have a simple node.js express webserver, that operates on both HTTP and HTTPS, but having issues with express's route parameters and HTTPS.

For those that don't know, express supports parameters in the routing like

app.get('/users/:userid', function(request, response)

When this 'userid' gets mapped to a  request.params.userid so that a url like "yoursite.com/users/123" request.params.userid will be 123.

Our function is 
    app.get('/api/v1/users/:userid', function (request, response) {

when using HTTP it works fine

when using HTTPS it doesn't with error "Cannot GET "..

However things without params e.g.

```
app.get('/api/v1/hello', function (request, response) {
```

work fine in both.

Any ideas what might be wrong?  If it can't be figured out then we'll have to remove all use of params and the nifty checks built into express, and go back to normal query string parsing.

Answer (score 0):

are you creating an http or https server?

With express you will need to wrap the app in an HTTPS object

```
var https = require('https');
var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(8000);
```

refer to http://nodejs.org/api/https.html for more info on HTTPS

Comment: I've created both.  The issue is not with node+https, it's with express+https and the specific use of it's special params in the route like /:userid that cause it to fail, but only in https